# Jersey (rest) file upload with @FormDataParam and no files gives 400 bad request

Tags: java, rest, jersey, swagger-ui, bad-request

I've made a resource with [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/), that can handle file uploads in `@FormDataParam`-annotated parameters (the resource is configured to receive query and header parameters too).

Testing with [Swagger-UI](http://swagger.io/swagger-ui/), as long as I send in a file along with other parameters, everything works fine.
But if I omit the files, and just fill in other parameters, my Java method doesn't receive the request (I verified this with the debugger), which instead ends early with a `400 Bad Request` error.

Class declaration:

```
@Path("/v1/users")
@Produces("application/json")
@Api("UploadDocumento")

public class UploadDocumentResourcesApiV10 extends CommonResourcesApi {
```

Method declaration:

```
@Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
@POST @Path("{userRef}/documents")
public Response uploadDocuments(
        @HeaderParam("X-Api-Token") String apiToken,
        @PathParam("userRef") String contactId,  
        @QueryParam("desc") String uploadDescription,
        @QueryParam("file1Desc") String file1Description, 
        @FormDataParam("file1") InputStream file1, @FormDataParam("file1") FormDataContentDisposition file1Meta,
        @QueryParam("file2Desc") String file2Description,
        @FormDataParam("file2") InputStream file2, @FormDataParam("file2") FormDataContentDisposition file2Meta) {
```

I've checked the browser request headers, in particular the `Content-Type` one, and in both cases they're the same.

Even a test with [cUrl](https://curl.haxx.se/) gives the same error.

What could be wrong?

Comment: did you find a solution? currently having this issue myself and researching an answer.

Comment: @kyle Nope, but later on I found that you can write equivalents to servlet filters, check [filters and interceptors](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html)

Comment: very nice! Thanks for the response.

Comment: I'm having this same issue.  I wonder why there isn't much out there about this issue.  Why can't I get it to accept any FormDataParams?